# C# picturebox throws System.InvalidOperationException: : "Object is currently in use elsewhere."

Tags: c#, multithreading, bitmap, backgroundworker, picturebox

I'm trying to take photos from my webcam every 3 seconds. But when I try to run the code I always get the above error. I searched through StackOverflow and found some solutions that suggested locking the resource. I thought I did it with a mutex but unfortunately, I still get the error.
I think it has something to do with the bitmap but I don't know where and which bitmap.

This is the code:

```
//Here I declare global variables
FilterInfoCollection filterInfoCollection;
VideoCaptureDevice videoCaptureDevice;

Int16 INTERVAL;
string SAVESPACE;

private static Mutex mutex = new Mutex();

//Here I start the stream of my webcam from where I get my images
private void startNewCamera()
        {
            videoCaptureDevice = new VideoCaptureDevice(filterInfoCollection[comboBox_Cameras.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
            videoCaptureDevice.NewFrame += VideoCaptureDevice_NewFrame;
            videoCaptureDevice.Start();
        }

//from my understanding this is where the live stream is being generated
//I also locked this one with a mutex
private void VideoCaptureDevice_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            mutex.WaitOne();
            pictureBox_Preview.Image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
            mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }


//Here I start with the backgroundworker from which I want to take a photo every 3 seconds
private void btn_Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //start recording
            if (backgroundWorker_camera.IsBusy != true)
            {
                backgroundWorker_camera.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }


//This is where the magic happens
//I lock the whole function but the error occurs nevertheless
private void backgroundWorker_camera_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            while (!backgroundWorker_camera.CancellationPending)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(INTERVAL);
                mutex.WaitOne();
                
                //HERE THE ERROR ALWAYS OCCURS
                pictureBox_Capture.Image = pictureBox_Preview.Image;

                var bitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox_Capture.Width, pictureBox_Capture.Height);
                pictureBox_Capture.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                    {
                        pictureBox_Capture.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, pictureBox_Capture.ClientRectangle);
                    }));

                System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat imageFormat = null;
                imageFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png;
                mutex.ReleaseMutex();                
            }    
        }
```

If there is anything I can improve on my question please let me know.
Thank you! :)

Comment: The whole point of a `BackgroundWorker` is to do background work. Anything relating to the UI is the complete opposite of background work. DO NOT touch the UI in the `DoWork` event handler. The `BackgroundWorker` has a mechanism for updating the UI during or after the background work. You need to learn how to use it. You might start [here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?542316).

Comment: I see that you're also calling `Invoke` on a control in that `DoWork` event handler. The whole point of the `BackgroundWorker` is so that you don't have to call `Invoke`. It works by calling methods and handling events, when done properly.

Comment: Ok but when I use normal threads would that solve any of the problems?

Comment: You should either use a `BackgroundWorker` properly or not at all but, regardless of what you do, you need to access the UI elements on the UI thread.

Comment: Ok, but how can I update the PictureBox in the UI thread without freezing the whole UI?

Comment: @jfst - You can do all of the heavy lifting in the background worker but just pass the image to the UI thread for updating the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Images in GDI+ are not thread-safe. What it means, basically - you cannot use one image from 2 threads simultaneously without some additional changes to your code.

Comment: Ok, so what would be the changes, or is there any better solution?

Comment: To avoid multiple threads accessing an image object I recommend always cloning the image and making sure each thread is working with its own clone.

Thread1_Img = MasterImage.Clone
Thread2_Img = MasterImage.Clone


This way each image is independent. This approach uses more memory, but is a safe way to work with images in a multi-threaded environment.

You should make sure you are cloning the image before handing it off to any new threads - otherwise, it's too late. You cannot safely clone an image once another thread begins using it.

Comment: SO doesn't disallow new users to post comments just for them to post answers that should be comments. If you haven't got an answer, don't post an answer. If you want to post a comment but can't, perform some activities to increase your score so that you can.

Comment: That sounds like a solution. But what is a MasterImage?

Answer (score -1):

I figured out the problem thanks to @NIRE GUPTAs' answer. Now I store the image in two separate variables for every thread. The updated functions look like this:

```
    //New global Image variables for every thread
    Image captureImageTH1;
    Image captureImageTH2;
    
    //The function where Livestream am commes from
    private void VideoCaptureDevice_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            captureImageTH1 = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
            captureImageTH2 = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();

            pictureBox_Preview.Image = captureImageTH1;
        }  


     //The function where I capture the Image every 3 seconds
     private void backgroundWorker_camera_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            string time;

            while (!backgroundWorker_camera.CancellationPending)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(INTERVAL);

                pictureBox_Capture.Image = captureImageTH2;

                var bitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox_Capture.Width, pictureBox_Capture.Height);
                pictureBox_Capture.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                    {
                        pictureBox_Capture.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, pictureBox_Capture.ClientRectangle);
                    }));
            }
         }
```

Comment: You don't ask questions in answers. Either this answers the question you asked or it doesn't. If it does then just post the answer and accept it. If this raises a new question then post a new question. Please spend some time in the Help Center to learn how this site works. It's a Q&A site, not a forum, so it doesn't work the same way as some other sites you might use to get help.

Comment: You're still setting the `Image` property of a `PictureBox` control in the `DoWork` event handler. DO NOT touch the UI on any thread but the UI thread.

Comment: @John but how could I change it another way without freezing the UI?

Comment: I tried it with Async/Await but I get the same error, that the PictureBox Is being used elsewhere.

Comment: You already know one way because you're already using it, i.e. calling `Invoke`. That said, you should be using `Invoke` with a `BackgroundWorker`. You should take the time to learn how to use a `BackgroundWorker` properly first, then you would have to ask how to use it. We should only be there for the things you can't work out for yourself, not teach you things so you don't have to learn them for yourself. You might start [here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?542316).

Comment: @jfst - This is not the answer to your problem. This is a hack that isn't always going to behave the way you think. John is right - do NOT access the UI from any thread other than the UI thread.